# Dynamic Model ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, model

I want to apply feature in mvc like. I have categories and those categories will have dynamic columns.

Now, for dynamic columns - I want to create xml file and storing in db. for e.g.

```
<col1 name="Description 1" type="textarea" isrequired="true">
</col1>
<col2 name="Sub Options" type="dropdown" isrequired="true">
 <item val="" name="">
 ...
</col2>
```

Now, How can I dynamically create view without specific model and data annotation? I also want to integrate validation, dynamic value binding etc.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to implement a weakly typed model?
I guess you could use a hash table with key based lookup as your model.
That way you can dynamically look up whatever data you need for specific scenarios.

Comment: I didnt get. Can I have any code snipplet to get more elaborative idea?